# How dangerous is i_am_bleeding.c?

Tags: c

I'm very new to C and basically all other low level stuff. I came across a piece of code and couldn't figure it out by myself: (I found this from [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CeeLanguage))

```
int main(){
    void (*i_am_bleeding)() = (void(*)())15;
    i_am_bleeding();
    return 0;
}
```

The article used it to support the argument:

> C is suffering a backlash of criticism for not having the
> characteristics of an application programming language, such as
> protecting the average programmer from cutting himself with sharp
> tools.

However, the author didn't explained the reason behind this, and no explanation was found elsewhere online. I tried to compile and run the code on my machine. It only gave me a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error.

So, could anyone tell me what happened to my machine when I execute the code, and the danger of doing it?

Comment: This is a crash not a security flaw. It sets the address of the function i_am_bleeding to 15, then calls it. As 15 will not normally be a valid address, you get a segmentation fault. I generally agree with the article's sentiment - most people should use a higher-level language, like Python.

Comment: Yeah, not seeing the security issue here.

Comment: @paj28: You can write wrong and potentially harmful code like that in any language. It is a stupid example as it **intentionally** violates the language standard. Tdy that with Pythons`s ctypes calling external functions or simply accessing non-existing attributes. A good programmer can write good code in any language (it just differs how long it takes), a bad programmer will write bad code in any language..

Comment: @Olaf - Between C and Python, there is a big difference in how easy it is to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: The C language was a major motivation behind the way operating systems work today.  Like getting it to generate that segfault to shut down the program in a controlled way without drawing blood.

Comment: @paj28: Not really. The difference is more how much you bleed, resp. how heavy your foot is armored. As with all heavy armor, movement speed decreases (which shows RPGs are sometimes good for a metaphor:-)

Comment: Python is so much better because it forces you to use a specific code and indentation style. Some programmers see this as a boon, others see it as draconian. Personally, I don't think it's the language's job to tell programmers how to write good code.

Comment: @Olaf - If your foot is armoured, then maybe you're not actually shooting yourself in the foot...? :) Metaphors are getting out of hand, but there is a serious point here. Most organisations do not have large teams of super star coders. Using a high-level language means that an average programmer is less likely to make an error that has a serious consequence.

Comment: @paj28 That's an unfounded argument. "Serious consequences" happen regardless of what language the program was written in, unless you think all the [major companies with data breaches](https://haveibeenpwned.com/) were using C. How can you shoot yourself in the foot with Python? Not having IDE settings that it wants you to, resulting in code that either won't run or runs incorrectly. That's a **real world example** unlike the OP.

Comment: @paj28: If you have a web-application exits with "unknown attribute" or another uncaught exception after you entered a lot of text, in the moment you "save" for instance. Anyway, you never developed high performance programs (HPC) or code for embedded systems with serious constraints (for you: less than 200MHz CPU, less than 32 bits, less than some MiB RAM, tight timing/high interrupt load, etc), did you? They are the vast majority of systems (still 8051 derivates outnumber x86/ARMv7A/v8 by decades). There are very good reasons to use C (not C++!). ...

Comment: @paj28: ... Also quantity does not imply quality. Considering the mass of rubbish programs, I strongly suspect using VHLLs like Python **in general** are better coded than C programs. Not talking about "baby's first program" stuff, etc. To end this: I don't use C on the desktop, but Python. That should make clear I very well know both worlds (and some more). It is not ours to recommend which language someone else shall use. At best we can point out the pros and cons, but that is not how stack overflow works. The higher abstraction the language, the higher abstraction the bugs - not less.

Comment: @Olaf I think there's a fundamental difference between "which language is better to use" and "average programmer is less likely to make an error that has a serious consequence" (paj28). The business cost between a server crashing because of undefined behavior in C versus millions of customer records leaking due to a badly written Python web program... well you be the judge.

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper: The choice between two heaps of dung. As asked, ther is no way to say which is more problematic. If the customers  move to a different service, both are problematic (unless your name is "Microsoft", "Apple" or "google"). Your point is moot, because you invoke the impresing there really is an alternative. As I commented: the higher abstration the language the higher abstraction the error. While a beginner will very likely not wrote a C server-application for production, they **actively do** in Python/Java/C# etc! Thus the impact of any bug will be much larger.

Comment: @Olaf What was implied in my argument is that the *server* software is likely to be written in C, while the web applications that handle the front-end, customer records, etc. would be written in C++, Python, Java, PHP, what have you. The former as you said would be unlikely to be written by an "average programmer". Shooting themselves in the foot is something that can be ignored (people deal with crashes on ancient software on Linux all the time.) Shooting yourself in foot in a web app directly affects millions of customers severely.

Answer (score 4):

> So, could anyone tell me what happened to my machine when I execute the code, and the danger of doing it?

In C, running mal-formed code that is not defined by the C spec is *undefined behavior* - UB.  `15` is not known to be a valid address of a function - so the assignment does not have specified behavior.  The next line that executes it is also UB.   C *allows* such code to be written and *may* even compile.  Yet since the behavior is not specified, the "danger of doing it" (running the executable) is that your computer *may* do anything.  Commonly code will simple crash.

```
void (*i_am_bleeding)() = (void(*)())15;  // UB
  i_am_bleeding();                        // UB
```

---

> C is suffering a backlash of criticism ...

C is 44+ years old.  It has been highly criticized before. It will likely be criticized decades from now - and still being used.

Answer (score 2):

The code declares a variable `i_am_bleeding` with the type: a function taking an unspecified number of arguments and returning nothing (`void`). It then takes the number `15`, casts it to the aforementioned type and assigns it to `i_am_bleeding`. The third line then calls that function.

The issue here is that the memory at address `15` in all likelihood does not contain a valid function and therefore should not be called as one. In primitive operating systems this may result in the program executing whatever unspecified data resides at `15` as if it were code, which is obviously a security flaw. However, in practically all (modern) operating systems the result is a `segmentation fault` (the program is using a piece of memory in a way it is not supposed to) and the program is killed.

This code is not a good example of the dangers of C though. The code does not conform to the language specification and exhibits *undefined behaviour*, which means the compiler/host environment are free to do what they want.

The cast `(void(*)())` tells the compiler *'This may look wrong, but I know what I am doing, so do it anyway'* and the compiler obliges. Without that cast most compilers would refuse to compile, or at least give a warning telling you it looks wrong.

C was designed to implement operating systems in (specifically Unix), and is therefore not always practical for writing user-level applications. But to criticise it for that would be to criticise a sledge-hammer because it isn't suitable for hanging paintings with.